# 2 questions. IDO mode not caching properly / forcing buffers to named windows

Tags: emacs, jde

## 1

My ido mode does not properly cache filenames / folders. It will list files inside a folder, but from a while ago without any of the newer files showing. Any suggestions ?

## 2

In jde, when I have multiple windows open, compiling on one window will create a corresponding "* name of the class *" that will open on the next window in order. This is fine if I only have one window open but can I get some help writing a function that I could use to :

Name a window
Force all buffers of *JDE compile server* to only ever open in that window if it exists
Force all run windows from jde in the form of * name of the class * to open in the same window if it exists.
Jde automatically names the buffer " * name of the class * ", I will probably dig around the codes to find an easy fix for that... so if the code could just force all windows using a regexp containing * jde run - filename * or something along the lines would also work.

Thanks for your help, first post here as well. I really would like just some ideas on what may be going wrong with 1, 2 if anyone is feeling kind.

Answer (score 0):

1 ) I'm not sure why youa re having this issue, but add the following to your .emacs:

> (defadvice ido-find-file (before auto-refresh-ido nil activate)
>        (setq ido-rescan t))

This will let ido know to update your files whenever you try and open a file with it - Although this should be working anyway, so you may have something else inhibiting it in your .emacs file.

I don't know about 2.

Comment: C-x C-f to read a file, then C-l to reread the directory.  C-l is bound to ido-reread-directory.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using JDE for a while, but ended up running away screaming, so I can't really help you there.

For 1), your best bet with any configuration bugs is to skip the loading of any of your customized files with

```
$ emacs -q
```

and see if that works. If it does, slowly add in your usual functionality until it breaks. Without any more information, there isn't a lot I can do to help.

If you feel like you have the problem reasonably narrowed down, try taking a look at the source code for the relevant functions. You'll learn a lot about Emacs and will often find the solution to your problem there.

Hope that helps.