# ido-mode outdated file list

Tags: emacs, emacs23, emacs24, ido-mode

I am using Emacs on Windows 7, and am finding that ido-mode is not picking up some files created since I started using it.

E.g. directory contains:

```
foo.txt
bar.txt
```

Open `foo.txt` in Emacs. Later, create `blah.txt` in the directory (also in Emacs).

When I do `C-x C-f` with ido-mode enabled, I see `foo.txt` and `bar.txt` but not the newly created `blah.txt`.

No matter how many times I open this file, it doesn't show. I either step out of ido with `C-f` or type the name exactly to get to it.

Any ideas what could fix this? I don't have FileNameCache enabled.

Comment: How do you create blah.txt?

Comment: Within Emacs, actually. It's not consistent, though, it is happening with a few files only at the moment

Comment: Is `blah.txt` saved when it happens? Can any other program see it?

Comment: Yes it's saved, I am able to use it as usual in the terminal and I can still open it in Emacs if I type the full name and 'confirm'. I can also C-f out of ido-mode and it gets picked up fine

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906290/2-questions-ido-mode-not-caching-properly-forcing-buffers-to-named-windows) asks a similar question (in addition to an unrelated one).

Answer (score 1):

Using ido-reread-directory (Bound to C-l) should solve this problem.

To read the files do

C-x C-f and then C-l to reread the directory when necessary.